# How to run a xquery with xml-file (containing value) as one of the bound variable

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I am new to using xquery and baseX. I am using the standalone prompt of baseX. I want to run an xquery, contained in abc.xq which can accept an input from a file, say, data.xml.

Basically, abc.xq has a bound variable 'request' which it will extract from data.xml payload.

How do i do this from command line of GUI of baseX?

Answer (score 1):

The [`BINDINGS`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#BINDINGS) option allows you to define variable assigments, which will then bound to a query. With the [`SET`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#SET) command, you can set these variables before running your query.

A new option for assigning external variables and the context item may be added to the GUI in a future version of BaseX.